# Expand a variable within variable right before echo

Tags: bash, echo

Example:

```
testing="test"
var="\"${testing} the variable\""
testing="Update"

echo "$var"
```

**Output**:
test the variable

**Required output**:
Update the variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are expanded when the string is used, they're not templates that remember the variable substitution.

If you need to do this, you need to put the variable literally into the string, and use `eval`.

```
testing="test"
var='"${testing} the variable"'
testing="Update"

eval "echo $var"
```

But `eval` is dangerous -- it will execute any shell commands in the string. A better solution would probably be to use some kind of placeholder string and replace it using the shell expansion operator.

```
var='#testing# the variable'
testing="Update"

echo "${var//#testing#/$testing}"
```

Comment: Or use process substitution with echo and store the result.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would use that to delay evaluating the variable.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Using the placeholder method.

Comment: `var="$(echo ${testing} the variable)"`

Comment: @Niloct That will expand `$testing` at the time of the assignment, not when you use `$var`.

Comment: Yes, it's an alternative to the template solution. Nevertheless it's not called process substitution sorry.

Comment: That's command substitution. Process subsitution is `<(command)`

Comment: Yeap. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03